# Does anybody have any tips for managing polymorphic nested resources in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphism, mongoid, nested-resources

In config/routes.rb:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end

resources :pictures do
  resources :comments
end
```

I would like to allow for more things to be commented on as well.

I'm currently using [mongoid](http://mongoid.org/) (mongomapper isn't as compatible with Rails 3 yet as I would like), and comments are an embedded resource (mongoid can't yet handle polymorphic relational resources), which means that I do need the parent resource in order to find the comment.

Are there any elegant ways to handle some of the following problems:

In my controller, I need to find the parent before finding the comment:

```
if params[:post_id]
  parent = Post.find(params[:post_id]
else if params[:picture_id]
  parent = Picture.find(params[:picture_id]
end
```

which is going to get messy if I start adding more things to be commentable.

Also `url_for([comment.parent, comment])` doesn't work, so I'm going to have to define something in my `Comment` model, but I think I'm also going to need to define an index route in the `Comment` model as well as potentially an edit and new route definition.

There might be more issues that I have to deal with as I get further.

I can't imagine I'm the first person to try and solve this problem, are there any solutions out there to make this more manageable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to do something similar in an app of mine. I took what I came up with and changed it around a bit, but I haven't tested it, so use with care. It's not pretty, but it's better than anything else I was able to think of.

In routes.rb:

```
resources :posts, :pictures

controller :comments do
  get '*path/edit' => :edit, :as => :edit_comment
  get '*path'      => :show, :as => :comment
  # etc. The order of these is important. If #show came first, it would direct /edit to #show and simply tack on '/edit' to the path param.
end
```

In comment.rb:

```
embedded_in :commentable, :inverse_of => :comments

def to_param
  [commentable.class.to_s.downcase.pluralize, commentable.id, 'comments', id].join '/'
end
```

In a before filter in comments_controller.rb:

```
parent_type, parent_id, scrap, id = params[:path].split '/'

# Security: Make sure people can't just pass in whatever models they feel like
raise "Uh-oh!" unless %w(posts pictures).include? parent_type

@parent = parent_type.singularize.capitalize.constantize.find(parent_id)
@comment = @parent.comments.find(id)
```

Ok, ugliness over. Now you can add comments to whatever models you want, and simply do:

```
edit_comment_path @comment
url_for @comment
redirect_to @comment
```

And so on.

Edit: I didn't implement any other paths in my own app, because all I needed was edit and update, but I'd imagine they'd look something like:

```
controller :comments do
  get    '*path/edit' => :edit, :as => :edit_comment
  get    '*path'      => :show, :as => :comment
  put    '*path'      => :update
  delete '*path'      => :destroy
end
```

The other actions will be trickier. You'll probably need to do something like:

```
  get  ':parent_type/:parent_id/comments'     => :index, :as => :comments
  post ':parent_type/:parent_id/comments'     => :create
  get  ':parent_type/:parent_id/comments/new' => :new,   :as => :new_comment
```

You'd then access the parent model in the controller using params[:parent_type] and params[:parent_id]. You'd also need to pass the proper parameters to the url helpers:

```
comments_path('pictures', 7)
```

Comment: This actually looks really good; with a few small changes I just implemented this, and for the most part it seems to be working fine. where is the documentation for the routing trickery you used in the first part so I can figure out how to connect the create, update, delete and index routes as well?

Comment: Okay, I think I figured out what you were doing and why you find it ugly.  Comment basically needs to be the last route defined because it will match anything.  I ended up using part of what you were doing and part of what I was doing to get everything implemented.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Ah, right, sorry if I was being unclear. Those splatted routes can be tricky.

Answer (score 2):

Ryan Bates covered polymorphic associations in [Railscasts #154](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association), but the example was for Rails 2 and Active Record. I managed to get his example working using Rails 3 and Mongoid by making a few changes.

In the Post and Picture models, add the following line:

```
embeds_many :comments, :as => :commentable
```

According to the [Mongoid associations documentation](http://mongoid.org/docs/associations/), all `embedded_in` associations are polymorphic. You don't need the `commentable_id` and `commentable_type` columns mentioned in the Railscast when using Mongoid, because the comment is a child of the commentable. In the Comment model, add the following line:

```
embedded_in :commentable, :inverse_of => :comment
```

Setup the routes in config/routes.rb like this:

```
resources posts do
  resources comments
end

resources pictures do
  resources comments
end
```

Add the following method to your comments controller as a `private` method. This is identical to Ryan's method:

```
def find_commentable  
  params.each do |name, value|  
    if name =~ /(.+)_id$/  
      return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)  
    end  
  end  
  nil  
end
```

In each of your comments controller actions where you need to find the comment, call the find_commentable method first to get the parent. Once the parent has been found, you can find the comment by ID, by searching through the commentable's comments. For example, in the edit action the code to find the comment would look like this:

```
@commentable = find_commentable  
@comment = @commentable.comments.find(params[:id])
```

To reduce the repetition of calling find_commentable at the start of every action, you could put a before filter at the top of the controller like this:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_commentable
  ...
```

And then change the return call in the find_commentable method to:

```
return @commentable = $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
```

I haven't encountered any problems using this method, but if you come across any issues please point them out.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing on Uriptical's answer, I found the relationships to work but named routes still did not.

I'm still pretty new at rails 3 but I found a simple solution using eval.

For instance, in my project, the polymorphic parents (represented in my app as the mongoid objects Product and Category) are defined as @imagable using a modification of find_comentable and the child being edited is referred to as @image.

a url such as `product_image_path(@imagable, @image)` which does
`GET => products/:product_id/images/` can be replaced with:

```
send("#{@imagable.class.name.downcase}_image_url", @imagable, image )
```

This works for all named paths. For instance:

```
link_to 'Edit', send("edit_#{@imagable.class.name.downcase}_image_path", @imagable, image ) 
link_to 'Destroy', send("#{@imagable.class.name.downcase}_image_url", @imagable, image), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete
```

The downside to this is it leaves sends all over your views and in controllers wherever you have redirects.

Is there a more elegant solution to do this via routes?

**replaced eval with send*

Comment: You could use [Polymorphic Routes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html), e.g. `edit_polymorphic_path(imageable, image)`